# Netty Server Push Usage and Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, push-notification, push, netty, nio

I'm now using Android as my Netty client. And Windows as my Netty Server.
Recently, I find a strange behavior on Netty.
When I open the server-side app, the memory is only 30MB.
But after several hours, it rises up to 300M. Its 10x compared to the original memory usage.
The longer I open the server, the more memory it will increase.

I don't know why this is happening. Is it normal?

By the way, since Netty doesn't support built-in server push feature.
So I use a static method to store all of the Channel in the map:

```
public static final Map<Integer, Channel> mapConcurrentIdChannel = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Channel>();
```

I map the channel ID to Channel.
For example: Whenever client A wants to push message to client B, the server will find the channel id and thus get the Channel instance, then use Channel.write(object) method. 
Is this a correct method to implement Push Message feature in Netty?
(If not, could you please suggest a good method to implement Push feature? Since there's no official docs mention that)
Also, I'm afraid this implementation causes "Memory Leak Problem" which I explain earlier.

**About using ChannelGroup:**
My scenario is if there are 5 people, A, B, C, D, E. Sometimes, A wants to send message to C, and sometimes B wants to send message to E. 
I can't predict when somebody will send message to somebody and who they will send to. So I can't add all the 5 people(connection) to the ChannelGroup, which writing to that group would broadcast the message to everyone.

I've searched on Google for a long time and nothing help on my problem I'm now facing.
Wish to hear some recommendations from Netty experienced developers, you!!

Thanks!!

Comment: did you find the solution for this? would be great if you share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use ChannelGroup[1] for this which is basically also just use a  ConcurrentMap put ensure the Channel is removed when it is closed etc.

[1] http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/group/DefaultChannelGroup.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My scenario is if there are 5 people, A, B, C, D, E. Sometimes, A wants to send message to C, and sometimes B wants to send message to E. I can't predict when somebody will send message to somebody and who they will send. So I can't add all the 5 people(connection) to the ChannelGroup, which writing to that group would broadcast the message to everyone. Is there any alternative to solving such kind of problem?

Comment: Should I create a Main ChannelGroup that saves all of the connections. Whenever client A wants to connect to client C, search A and C in the Main ChannelGroup and then add A and C to a new ChannelGroup?  BTW, after checking the code, I think the memory problem might come from another component that is not related to Netty.